# ssh proxycommand with kerberos

Tags: ssh, kerberos

I can ssh from my machine `A` to machine `B` using ssh-keys. On machine `B` I hence receive a Kerberos ticket to login to machine `C`; following works then:

```
ssh -At machineB ssh -At machineC
```

I want to login to `C` from `A` directly, therefore, I added following lines to my `~/.ssh/config`?:

```
Host machineC
    ProxyCommand ssh -q machineB nc -q0 %h %p
```

But now, I will be asked for a password; Is there some way of a password-less login?

Comment: I looking for solution too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with `ProxyCommand`, if you need to authenticate from the host B. You still need to use

```
ssh -At machineB ssh -At machineC
```

Comment: Is there some way to specify this command in the ssh-config? This would enable me to save some implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way I am aware of. At worst, you can set up some bash functions/aliases to achieve the same.